# Tkinter using append to print to a label

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

I have been trying to return the fuction `printLabel` to print "Hello
world!", but I  am not too sure how to progress further:

I would like to use `lambda` in order to print my append strings in the label when the button is clicked but this displays without the button being clicked. My
code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):   

    def printLabel(self):
        self.hello = []
        self.hello.append('Hello\n')
        self.hello.append('World!')
        print(self.hello)  
        return(self.hello)        

    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.buttonA()
        self.viewingPanel()

    def buttonA(self):
        self.firstPage = Button(self, text="Print Text", bd=1, anchor=CENTER, height = 13, width = 13, command=lambda: self.printLabel())
        self.firstPage.place(x=0, y=0)        

    def viewingPanel(self):  
        self.panelA = Label(self, bg='white', width=65, height=13, padx=3, pady=3, anchor=CENTER, text="{}".format(self.printLabel()))
        self.panelA.place(x=100, y=0)        


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Tk")
    root.geometry('565x205')
    app = Example(root)
    app.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The lambda function for print can be lambda x: print(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few modifications to your code, and it should work the way you want:

```
from tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):  

    def printLabel(self):
        self.hello.append('Hello\n')
        self.hello.append('World!')  
        return(self.hello) 

    # Added 'updatePanel' method which updates the label in every button press.
    def updatePanel(self):
        self.panelA.config(text=str(self.printLabel()))

    # Added 'hello' list and 'panelA' label in the constructor.
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.hello = []
        self.panelA = None
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.buttonA()
        self.viewingPanel()

    # Changed the method to be executed on button press to 'self.updatePanel()'.
    def buttonA(self):
        self.firstPage = Button(self, text="Print Text", bd=1, anchor=CENTER, height = 13, width = 13, command=lambda: self.updatePanel())
        self.firstPage.place(x=0, y=0)        

    # Changed text string to be empty.
    def viewingPanel(self):  
        self.panelA = Label(self, bg='white', width=65, height=13, padx=3, pady=3, anchor=CENTER, text="")
        self.panelA.place(x=100, y=0)        


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Tk")
    root.geometry('565x205')
    app = Example(root)
    app.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: After completing as suggested this will not print to the Label but to the console, is there away around this please?

Comment: I have added this within viewingPanel:  text="{}".format(self.printLabel())),  but I want this to appear when i click the button, rather than when the GUI is executed.

Comment: @pythonnewbie thanks for letting me know, edited my answer. Let me know for further changes.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, this is how i was hoping for my GUI to be.